# How to get all exposed routes in Spark framework

Tags: java, spark-framework

In java spark web framework a route is defined as

```
get("/", (request, response) -> {
// Show something
```

});

In my application I define multiple routes. Is there any way I can get **all** the exposed routes of the application?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to automatically find REST routes as they do not have a standard registry service. 
Although, you can document them using [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) or even store them using chrome applications such as **Postman** or **Advanced Rest Client**.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible now in spark 2.9.4

```java
import spark.Spark;
import spark.routematch.RouteMatch;

// somewhere after route definitions

for (RouteMatch route : routes()) {
    String method = route.getHttpMethod().toString();
    if (method.equals("before") || method.equals("after")) continue;
    System.out.printf("--> %-7s %s\n", method.toUpperCase(), route.getMatchUri());
}
```

output

```
--> POST    /internal/update_notification
--> GET     /internal/history
--> GET     /internal/history_details
--> GET     /ping
```

Comment: https://github.com/perwendel/spark/pull/1100